# Share a folder on PC with two NICs

Tags: domain, shared-folders, sharing

On my workplace, I have a PC with two NICs. The onboard NIC is connected with a domain, the other one is connected directly with an another PC that is not a domain PC (Workgroup PC).

I created a Folder on the Domain PC which need to be accessed via the second NIC from the Workgroup PC.

The question is...how do I do that? Do I have to add the User from the Workgroup PC when I share the folder? Can I add the User from the Workgroup PC at all? I don't need to set a password, they are placed right to each other, I just need to copy files to that folder, that's all.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows file sharing doesn't require matching accounts, it only requires *an* account. At first the client PC will *try* to use the same credentials it already knows, but if the server PC doesn't recognize you, the client will simply show an authentication prompt and you can enter whatever you want in there. (File permissions are also checked according to the user who "logged in" to the share, so if a standalone client provides domain user credentials, it'll have the privileges of that domain user.)

- So depending on how the domain is configured, it might be possible to simply enter your domain credentials when trying to access the share, nothing more. (Note that this will use NTLM authentication rather than the more secure Kerberos.)
- But if the domain controllers are configured to refuse NTLM, you could create a local account on the server PC (e.g. via lusrmgr.msc). For convenience you can set it to have the same username and password as on the client PC, though again that's not a requirement.

  With this second option, you will need to grant the new account access to your shared files, either through the folder's "Permissions" tab or using icacls.